# How to split the values after decimal points?

Tags: java, android, split, decimal

I cannot able split the decimal value after the decimal point and I tried some possible answers using **split** but it is not achievable.Please suggest some possible solutions achieve this

**Latitude:13.8989989988**

the solution which I need is: **13.898** and remaining values **998998** separately

Comment: _I tried some possible answers using split but it is not achievable_ Show what you have tried there please. If this is a numeric, then you just need to substract the integer part of this value (to get an approximation, since floating value is not precise)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a regular expression with a look-behind

```
"13.8989989988".split("(?<=\\.\\d{3})");
```

The result of this is an array containing `"13.898"` and `"9989988"`.

The regular expression here means "empty string preceded by a dot and three digits", which gives you the match that you want.

Comment: based upon the existing question it is unclear whether the variable is even a String

Comment: I would upvote you gladly but I try not to promote regex answer since there are enough post about it. OP didn't search enough. (Nothing about you of course)

Comment: Good point, and I guess she could always make it into a String

Answer (score 1):

You can get the two parts as numeric values by using `Math.floor`:

```
double lat = 13.8989989988;
double part1 = Math.floor(lat * 1e3) / 1e3; // 13.898
double part2 = Math.floor(Math.ceil((lat - part1) * 1e11) / 1e2) // 998998.0
```

---

### In Detail

According to Dawoods comment on this answer, this may not be the best approach. Nevertheless here is a more detailed explanation of what’s going on.

> As a general rule, using double to deal with decimals in Java is a bad
>   idea. If you're going to do this kind of manipulation arithmetically
>   (as opposed to using String like my answer), then the best policy is
>   always to use the BigDecimal class. Never expect a double to behave
>   like a decimal. ***— Dawood ibn Kareem***

**Getting the first part**
Move the decimal point to the left by the desired decimals length, then `floor` and move the decimal point back.

```
double lat = 13.898998995;
double step1 = lat * 1e3; // 13898.998995
double step2 = Math.floor(step1) // 13898.0
double step3 = step2 / 1e3 // 13.898
```

**Getting the second part**
We move the decimal point like we did for getting the first part, but use a combination of `ceil` and `floor` to prevent rounding issues. That’s why we move the decimal point a little bit more.

```
double step1 = lat - part1; // 0.000998995 = the rest

// number length of 6 + we already got 3 decimals + 2 decimals for rounding up, then down
// 1e6 + 1e3 + 1e2 = 1e11
double step2 = Math.ceil(step1) * 1e11; // 00099899500.0
double step3 = Math.floor(step2 / 1e2); // 000998995.0
```

Comment: Good point @DawoodibnKareem – thx! I updated my answer. Are you happy with this? ;-)

Comment: Man, you really got me now.

Comment: I agree. Already upvoted your answer, but thought this could also be a starting point for somebody else. I’ll update my answer with some explanation at least.

Comment: Would like to see the `BigDecimal` approach, @DawoodibnKareem. I also updated the answer. Hope you’re okay with being cited. ;-)

Comment: Well, I've made you work really hard for it, but here (finally) is my upvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
    double lat=13.8989989988;
    double seperated = Math.floor(lat*100.0)/100.0;
    System.out.println(seperated);
    System.out.println(lat-seperated);
```

Comment: Did you try this?  I think the result might surprise you.

Comment: 13.89 --- first print
0.008998998799999214 -- second

Answer (score 0):

For those who would prefer an arithmetic solution, rather than String manipulation, I offer the following.

```
BigDecimal original = new BigDecimal("13.898998998");
BigDecimal part1 = original.setScale(3, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
BigInteger part2 = original.subtract(part1).unscaledValue();
System.out.println(part1 + ", " + part2);  // prints 13.898, 998998
```

This will even preserve a trailing zero in the original String.

The important point here is that these numbers are decimals, so should never be stored in a `float` or `double`.  If you don't want to suffer from rounding errors, always use `BigDecimal` to store your decimals.